# How to fix KeyError: 'web' in Odoo8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nginx, odoo-8, odoo

I have installed Odoo8 and it is running with Nginx.

When I access to the URL where Odoo is supposed to run, I only see the black topbar with no menus, the rest of the page is empty.

The log spits out this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/http.py", line 544, in
>   _handle_exception
>       return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/http.py", line 581, in
>   dispatch
>       result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/http.py", line 318, in
>   _call_function
>       return self.endpoint(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/http.py", line 810, in **call**
>       return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/http.py", line 410, in
>   response_wrap
>       response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo_8/src/linked-addons/web/controllers/main.py", line
>   591, in bootstrap_translations
>       if http.addons_manifest[addon_name].get('bootstrap'): KeyError: 'web'

I checked that I have module web at the mentioned path, with the right permissions and the right owner. I was not able to find a solution for this problem.

Anyone experienced the same situation? I think it can be a problem of Nginx (because recently I made several Odoo 8 installations in different servers and following exactly the same steps in each one, but the other ones did not use Nginx).

I paste here the configuration of the Nginx site of Odoo:

```
server_tokens off;

server {
    server_name my.server.name.com;

    large_client_header_buffers 16 8m;
    client_max_body_size        200m;

    location / {
      proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8069;
      proxy_buffers         16 8m;
      proxy_buffer_size     8m;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
      proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $http_x_real_ip;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_connect_timeout 600;
      proxy_send_timeout    600;
      proxy_read_timeout    600;
      send_timeout          600;

      location ~ ^/(.*)/static/(.*) {
        alias /opt/odoo/odoo_8/src/linked-addons/$1/static/$2;

        expires +30d;
        access_log    off;
        log_not_found off;
      }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: That's the full traceback? Sometimes just a python lib is missing, but the traceback comes right before the "KeyError" 'web' error.

Comment: well have you removed `nginx` to see if the issue still persists, so you'll know the origin of the problem exactly (i doubt it's from nginx)

Comment: Yes, that is the full traceback of the error, it does not tell very much. I did not remove Nginx because it is installed on a remote server whose owner is other person, so I would rather not to remove it, but if there is not another way, I guess I will have to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not have idea why, but it is fixed. What I did:

1. I removed all the Odoo modules I had downloaded from GitHub.
2. I downloaded then again (exactly like I did the first time).
3. I restarted Odoo service.
4. This time I got two errors instead of one. One was the *KeyError: 'web'*, like earlier, the other one was asking for *Wand* package.
5. I installed *Wand*: `pip install Wand`
6. After refreshing, same situation, two errors, but the other one this time was asking for *MagickWand*.
7. I installed it: `apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`
8. After refreshing, again, two errors, this time Odoo was asking for *pycoda*.
9. I installed *pycoda*: `pip install pycoda`
10. I restarted Nginx and Odoo services, just in case, and it worked. No more errors.

I cannot explain why the log did not tell me anything about the other errors in the first installation, and it only noticed me about the `KeyError: 'web'`.

Comment: These import problems are always difficult to see. But when odoo can't load web module, it's often just a missing python lib.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the same on all versions of Odoo, and this error will usually follow some other errors. **It's important to fix your errors from top to bottom.**

The error has to to with a **broken, missing or outdated python modules**.

Take a look at your Odoo log to see if you see any import errors...

```
...
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from x import y
ImportError: cannot import etc...
```

Now just make sure your install or update the import in question.

```
pip install y
pip install --upgrade y
```

Then restart your Odoo instance or docker container and try again.